# zend + doctrine 2 doctrine manager, where is it?

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

i see everyone using this:

```
 Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()
```

when i do this, its error is:

Class 'Doctrine_Manager' not found

how do i load this ?so that i can start get instances from doctrine manager?

i want to load this:

```
$con = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->connection();
$st = $con->execute("...............");


$result = $st->fetchAll();
```

where can autoload this , so i can call the getInstance() function from anywhere?

thanks...

Comment: Are you using Doctrine 2 itself ? Noway for Doctrine2 is using namespace and not the namespace as `Doctrine_Manager` . This seems to 1.2 or 1.X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Doctrine_Manager` is part of version 1.2, not 2. If you are actually using 1.2, you need to let the autoloader know to load classes under the `Doctrine_` prefix.

To do so, add this to your application configuration file...

```
autoloaderNamespaces.Doctrine = "Doctrine_"
```

You also need to ensure the doctrine classes can be found on the include path. If they aren't in your "library" folder or otherwise part of the `include_path` directive, add this...

```
includePaths.Doctrine = "/path/to/Doctrine-1.2/lib"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for the EntityManager?

If so, [here](http://jeboy25.blogspot.com/2010/08/doctrine-2-and-zend-framework-110.html) you can find a tutorial how to configure.

Also there is a library call [Bisna](http://www.krueckeberg.org/notes/bisna.html) for integrating ZF+Doctrine2, [here](http://www.zendcasts.com/unit-testing-doctrine-2-entities/2011/02/) is a good tutorial video for configuring it